# How can I remove all rows for which the variable YYYYMM ends with 13?

Tags: r

I have a variable that contains year and month (`YYYYMM`) but as the dataset is constructed there is a "month" 13 in the data set which is a summation of each years all months. Those rows I want to delete.

My question is: How can I remove all rows for which the variable `YYYYMM` ends with 13?

Comment: provide an example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `substr` to extract the numbers in the 5th and 6th position, create a logical vector (`!=13`) and subset the rows.

```
 df1[substr(df1[,'var'],5,6)!=13,]
```

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks for answering. What are the 5 and 6 for? R responds with:  Error in x$YYYYMM : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Do you know what that means?

Comment: @Elina Are you sure you have a `data.frame`?  Can you post the `str(yourdataframe)`

Comment: @Elina Can you test the edited code.  May be you have a `matrix`.

Comment: @Elina The 5 and 6 are the positions i.e. if the number is 201409, then 5th and 6th positions extracted by `substr` is `'09'`

Comment: I realized that my data was a mess. Now the command you suggested works perfectly -- thanks!!